# How to run java code in terminal

Tags: java, bash, terminal

How do i run this piece of code? It's a clicker.

```
public class Counter{

    private int value;

    public Counter(int initialValue){
        value = initialValue;
    }
    public void click(){
        value = value + 1;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

I'm running osX and i want this 'executed' in the terminal. The file (Counter.java) is placed on the desktop, therefor the first thing i do in the terminal is

```
cd desktop
javac Counter.java
```

After this i want to call click, but i'm not sure how to. I tried 'java Counter.click()' but it gives me the error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' .

This is a very noobish question, sorry :)

Comment: I should add that i'm, obviously, very new to java.

Comment: Then added to the question ! Not as a comment

Comment: You obviously need to go and read the basic tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just created a class `Counter`.
To run this class you must make another class Launcher.java or something and add

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create Clicker here
}
```

In this function, you create a object of `Counter`

```
Counter counter = new Counter(0);
```

Then you can execute member-function on this new Counter object:

```
 counter.click();
```

If you would want to add some userinput, i suggest you take a look at [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)
ex.
You could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String choice="";
        Counter counter= new Counter(0);
        do{
           choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("message");
           switch (choice) {
            case click:
            counter.click();
            break;
                case getValue:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,counter.getValue());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }  
        }while(!choice.equals("close");      
    }
```

then export your project as a RUNNABLE jar.

ps. JOptionPane is just one solution, Google is your friend !

Answer (score 1):

You cant call member methods like Counter.click() use main method in it and then try to run as

```
$java Counter
```